# Access VBA Export Form Spreadsheet to Excel without OutputTo

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, export, ms-office

I am currently trying to export an Access form to a ".xlsm" prepared Excel-File. Before switching to my template with macros, I used

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "frmFilteredInformation", acFormatXLSX, strFilePath, False
```

yet there is no acFormatXLSM i could use. The only other way I could think of is exporting the form to an .xlsx, followed by copying the table to the .xlsm. Are there any better ways I could do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The format of XLSM is the same as XLSX. It is only a naming problem. Use the `acFormatXLSX` format and name your output file `"whatever.xlsm"`.

Comment: Hi Olivier, thanks for your fast response. Sadly, my export still won't work this way - when directly exporting to a .xlsm file, I cannot open that file as Excel states it is corrupted. It works fine when naming the file .xlsx or exporting in a .xlsx, but for .xlsm, the command does not seem to work.